# Serial communication freezes between python ide and arduino

Tags: python, arduino, serial-communication

Serial communication freezes after some time while sending bytes from python ide to arduino , I am detecting the shapes from camera and sending data to arduino through usb cable. and then arduino control the robotic arm to pick them and place them in predefined boxes. while freezing arduino both tx/rx lights goes still high and python ide  window in which video is showing freezes. please suggest me the possible solution . if rx register of arduino overflowing ??